# mysqli query issue. mysqli_real_escape_string error

Tags: php, mysqli, mysql-real-escape-string

Having trouble with a mysqli query - specifically the `WHERE stoname=` clause.

This doesn't work:

```
$result = @mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM thedb  WHERE coname='{$_SESSION['user']}' AND stoname='{$_SESSION['store']}' ");
```

If I echo `$_SESSION['store']` then it prints as `o\'store` which matches what's the in the database. Yet this doesn't work.

However, if I echo `mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,($_SESSION['store']))` then it prints `o\\\'store` which is NOT what's in the database. Yet it works.

```
$result = @mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM thedb WHERE user='{$_SESSION['user']}' AND stoname='".mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,($_SESSION['store']))."' ");
```

I accept that I have working code, but I'm confused as to why this the case. Can anyone explain what I've done / am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: When you say the first doesn't work, do you mean it returns no result, or that it breaks the SQL statement resulting in error? You'll miss errors unless you remove the `@` from `@mysqli_query()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your table literally contains `o\'store` then `mysqli_real_escape_string()` has done its job correctly.  The function's purpose is to escape a string for safe inclusion inside a SQL statement, not to be an exact literal match for what is actually already in your table.

The table value contains literally `\'`. When you use that value directly in the SQL statement, the backslash is *misinterpreted* as an escape character to the `'` rather than as a literal `\` as appears in your table. So the query produces no results because the executed SQL statement is:

```
# MySQL sees only an escaped ' and no \
SELECT * FROM thedb  WHERE coname='something' AND stoname='o\'store'
```

...meaning the value of `stoname` actually compared is just `o'store` without `\`, because `\` has been discarded by MySQL as an escape character.

So `mysqli_real_escape_string()` produces a value with two changes.

First, the literal `'` in your original string is backslashed escaped as `\'` for use in the SQL.

Then, the literal `\` already in your string is itself backslash-escaped so that it can be understood as a literal characer by MySQL rather than an escape character. That results in `\\`. Combined with the escaped `\'`, you now have `\\\'`.

MySQL receives that string `\\\'` and is able to correctly interpret it as one literal `\` followed by one literal `'` after discarding the extra `\` escape character before each. The condition matches the column's actual value and your query is successful.

```
# MySQL sees an escaped \ followed by an escaped '
SELECT * FROM thedb  WHERE coname='something' AND stoname='o\\\'store'
```

#### About storage...

We don't know much about how your table originally received its value, but I have a hunch it was stored in an escaped form. If the string `o\'store` was originally `o'store` without the `\`, it suggests that an escaped value was inserted in the table. That is not usually done, and is undesirable. Correct use of `mysqli_real_escape_string()` at the time of data insertion should store the *original* string rather than an escaped string.  Escaping is only done when constructing SQL statements.

Comment: Thank you for your lengthy reply. I've been looking at these backslashes so long I think my brain's about to implode & I'll have to read your reply over a few times.  However, it sounds like the database is the main mistake.  Ignoring binding etc for a moment, shouldn't a value be escaped before storing? Would you expect to store that value as `o'store` rather than `o\'store` in the table?

Comment: @devsie Is the original value supposed to be `o'store`? If so, then it should be escaped _before_ storing, which means the actual value stored is _no longer escaped_.  The escaping is only relevant to the SQL string. Without the backslash, as you know, the SQL would break. But used properly, the escaped value never makes it into the database, and if the database does contain escaped values, something has gone wrong with how they were inserted. A common issue is double-escaping due to `addslashes()`, for example.

Comment: ^^ That still sounds complicated. Shorter answer - Yes, I would expect the _stored_ value to be `o'store`, unescaped.  The \ is for the query parser, not for the data storage.

Comment: Yes the original value is meant to be `o'store`.  No `addslashes` used.  Looking up the code,  `$stoname = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim(ucwords(strtolower($_POST['stoname']))));` and `@mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO sto_details (stoname) VALUES('$stoname') ");` seems to be all that's going on.

Comment: @devsie Hmm, do you have [magic quotes enabled](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) An evil mis-feature of older PHP versions that was finally taken away in 5.4... That is another likely explanation but I didn't volunteer it because it's less common these days.

Comment: Check `var_dump(get_magic_quotes_gpc())`, also check `var_dump($_POST['stoname'])`.

Comment: You're right, magic quotes isn't on.  I'll have to check that sto_details.stoname doesn't get editing anywhere else on the site.  Thanks again for the help, something for me to be working on.

Comment: I think corrupt data may have got into the DB.  If the initial form had an error, then the fields got repopulated with escaped strings. So then the data got escaped again and put into the DB.

Comment: I'm gonna go through site and update to mysqli prepared statements.  This should remove the requirement to escape data shouldn't it?  Just going to take me while. :(

Comment: Correct. Using prepared statements with ? placeholders and bind_param()  instead of variables eliminates the need to escape. More secure too, since it protects against merely forgetting to escape a valyt